# How to style a button when disabled?

Tags: javascript

I have a button that depending on a value it turns disabled. When it's disabled I want to change the css of said button to a backgroundColor grey. This is the css of the button when enabled:

```
$('#buttons').append('<button id="aceite" style="background-color:#4CAF50;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 12px;text-align: center;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); margin:5px;">Aceitar</button>');
```

This is the code that enables or disables the button:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#aceite', function () {
                    if (item.estado == "aceite") {
                        aceite.disabled = true;

                        //I've tried like this, but it doesn't work
                        aceite.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 

                       concluido.disabled = false;
                       recusado.disabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //More Code
                    }
                });
```

Why it's it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `disabled` attribute, and define CSS styling for buttons with it, this would also work if you set the `disabled` property to `true` in JavaScript:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#another-button');
button.disabled = true; // Make the button disabled via javascript
```

```css
button[disabled] {
  /* Apply some sort of style to buttons with the disabled attribute */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Regular button</button>
<button disabled>Disabled button</button>
<button id="another-button">Another disabled button</button>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because my button are appended by a function

Comment: CSS Rules would still apply to them, no matter how they are added to the document, see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/v108cmkh/ Nevertheless, you should at least try.

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I've discover the error, instead of using the variabvle that I had (aceite) i needed to use

```
document.getElementById("aceite").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
```

Thank you to everyone that responded.

Answer (score -1):

Your code had bug, Try this following code

first of all `item` was not declared, so I just created so that our if condition work. and also commented `concluido.disabled = false;` and `recusado.disabled = false;` because they were not defined in your code.

And know if you click your button color is changing.

```
$(document).on('click', '#aceite', function () {
    console.log("clicked..");
    var item = {
        estado: "aceite"
    };
     if (item.estado == "aceite") {
       aceite.disabled = true;

       //I've tried like this, but it doesn't work
       aceite.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 

       // concluido.disabled = false;
       // recusado.disabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
       //More Code
     }
});
```

Comment: Hey, is this helped?